# Dialog size increases and goes beyond screen when datatable's clearFilter invoked

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a p:commandlink which when clicked opens a dialog containing p:datatable which has a globalFilter for itself.
Please note that the commandlink action doSomething() contains code to populate table's list.
At first, I click the p:commandlink, it opens the dialog containing p:datatable, I apply some filter and just close the dialog.
Again when the commandlink is clicked, the dialog appears at central position, filter is cleared and then, dialog goes beyond screen.

Code :-

```
<p:commandLink action="#{Bean.doSomething()}"  ajax="true" oncomplete="PF('table').clearFilters();PF('dialog').show();" update="dialog" >
     <h:outputText value="Add"  />  
 </p:commandLink>   


<p:dialog id="dialog" widgetVar="dialog"  width="1100"  modal="true" >  
     <p:dataTable  id="table"   widgetVar="modGrpsList" value="#{Bean.list}"    rows="10" filteredValue="#{Bean.filteredList}"    >

        <f:facet name="header"> 
        <p:inputText id="globalFilter" value="#{Bean.searchTextDialog}" onkeyup="PF('modGrpsList').filter();" />
        </f:facet>

        // datatable contents
      </p:dataTable>
</p:dialog>
```

I think my execution order of dialog opening, filtering and updating table is wrong.
Can anyone specify, how should I clear the datatable filter, update the datatable and then open the dialog so that it by default, gets openened at the center of screen.

**Edit :-**
'Dialog goes beyond screen', by that, I mean only half contents of my dialog is visible on the screen, rest of the contents go below the screen.I, then have to drag it to the top to make the whole dialog visible.
I am using **primefaces v5.0**

Comment: what is 'goes beyond screen'? Screenshot? And what PF version?

Comment: @Kukeltje, edited my question

Comment: Tried a newer version of PF?

Comment: @Kukeltje I can't use a new version for now, I think, I am getting this issue due to the update="dialog", I am updating the whole dialog instead of datatable.

Comment: If you think you update to much, update less, easy to try... (updating the full dialog should work, but I never do that, always update just the contents (unless the title must change). And regarding the newer version. Just TRY, I never said use in production. If it works in a newer version, you can compare code (it IS open) and see if you can find a cause. I personally don't have the time to try to find workarounds for old versions which might work in newer versions. Sorry.

Comment: @Kukeltje, It worked, I only updated the datatable inside the dialog and is working perfectly, and thanks for the tips, also, will check the same code in  newer versions too.Thanks